# When running a python program with multiple source files the constructor acts differently from the function

Tags: python

main file.py

```
from resources import *
alist[0].update()
print (blist)
```

resources.py

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
    def update(self):
        global blist
        blist=blist+[b()]
class b:
    def __init__(self):
        self.y=0
blist=[]
alist=[a()]
```

This program should create a new instance of class b in blist when alist[0].update() is called, but after it has run print(blist) it displays only an empty list. I have also tried the same code where class a is defined like this

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
        global blist
        blist=blist+[b()]
    def update(self):
        pass
```

and it successfully creates an instance in list b. I really need it to create another instance with the function rather than the constructor, how do I do this? Any comments are appreciated!

P.S. This ONLY happens when running multiple source code files.

Comment: Do you have a really good reason for using globals?  They're generally considered very bad practice in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blist=blist+[b()]` re-defines `blist`. It doesn't modify the original object, which is what your `blist` in the other source file points to.

You should `.append` to the original list instead:

```
blist.append(b())
```